# MySQL GROUP BY on large tables

Tags: mysql, performance, innodb

I have a table with over 75 millions registers. I want to run a group by to summarize this registries.

The table structure is:

```
CREATE TABLE `output_medicos_full` (
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `term` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `hash` varchar(40) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `url` varchar(2000) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`name`,`term`,`hash`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I want execute the query bellow, but is taking so long using a dedicate mysql server 5.5 with 4GB RAM:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE report
SELECT 
    `hash`
    ,CASE UPPER(SUBSTRING_INDEX(url, ':', 1)) 
        WHEN 'HTTP' THEN 1
        WHEN 'HTTPS' THEN 2
        WHEN 'FTP' THEN 3
        WHEN 'FTPS' THEN 4
        ELSE 0 end
    ,url
FROM output_medicos_full
GROUP BY `hash`;
```

On table report there is an unique index on hash column

Any help to speed it up?

Thank's

Comment: Of course. You are using functions on all records. Not even an index would make that faster. On other DB engines that query would fail. Why don't you aggregate the URL column and what output do you expect?

Comment: @juergend Some RDBMS (e.g. Oracle) _do_ have functiom indices, though MySQL may not have this.

Comment: @ your hash value is varchar (40 ) so it will have considerable length and this can impact your performance although you indexed it

Comment: @juergen d @Tim Biegeleisen thanks for your comments. I want generate an subset (new table) with all urls distinct. The column `hash` just has SHA-1 value of url.
    I've changed some server parameters to
    innodb_buffer_pool_size = 2G
    innodb_log_file_size = 1G
    max_connections = 500
    innodb_file_per_table = 1
    innodb_log_buffer_size = 128M
    query_cache_size = 0
    max_allowed_packet = 100M

Answer (score 2):

The main cost here is all the I/O.  The entire table needs to be read.

`innodb_buffer_pool_size = 2G` is dangerously high for 4GB of RAM.  If swapping occurs, performance will suffer terribly.

Since the `hash` is a SHA1, it is extremely likely to be unique across a mere 75M urls.  So that `GROUP BY` will yield 75M rows.  This is probably not what you wanted.  Once you rewrite the query, we can discuss optimizations.